# Ruby on Rails - Join Two Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following:

**Schema**

```
create_table "mouldings", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "suppliers_code"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "supplier_id"
  t.decimal  "length"
  t.decimal  "cost"
  t.decimal  "width"
  t.decimal  "depth"
end

create_table "suppliers", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

**Models**

```
class Moulding < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Set up associations
  belongs_to :suppliers

end

class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Associations
  has_many :mouldings, :dependent => :destroy

end
```

**Controller**

```
  def show
    @moulding = Moulding.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @moulding }
    end
 end
```

I want to join the two tables so I can include the supplier's name in a view.  What is the correct syntax for the controller?

Comment: You might want to mention Ruby in more than just the tags.  Title and body might be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off your syntax is a bit off in your moldings model. It's should be `supplier` singular

```
class Moulding < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Set up associations
  belongs_to :supplier

end
```

If you want the supplier name use this in the controller or view.

```
@moulding.supplier.name
```

Also if you're going to be looping through a bunch of moldings you'll want to include suppliers in your initial query so it doesn't run a query for each time it lists a suppliers name. The syntax for that is:

```
@moulding = Moulding.find(params[:id],:include => :supplier)
```

I'd also suggest taking a look at the official Active Record [Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and [Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) guides (for Rails 3)

Comment: @freshest  You may get some use out of guides.rubyonrails.org.  Check the sections on active record query interface, layout and rendering, and action controller overview in particular.

Comment: dub Many thanks for the help.  If I use Moulding.find(params[:id],:include => :supplier) in the controller what syntax do I use in the view to reference the supplier name?

Comment: The syntax doesn't change from what i posted above. The only difference if that if you were to say want to get the supplier names of 1000 moldings this would be a significant performance boost.

Answer (score 1):

From a broad perspective, you can use either :joins or :include in your ActiveRecord statement.  The major difference is that joins will do an inner join while include will do an outer join.  http://asciicasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins